# Calculated Column result equals null

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create an "If" formula that will return lastname and firstname if the middlename column is blank. I also want the result to be lastname, firstname, and middlename if the middlename column is not blank.

This current formula I'm using returns "null" if a middlename is not present:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Middle),CONCATENATE(Last, ", " ,First), CONCATENATE(Last, ", ", First," ",Middle))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula works in my SPO site.

[image]

Is the middle name column a Single Line of Text column? How is the data added? Typed, Imported, via web service?

You might try:

```
middle = ""
```

in place of:

```
ISBLANK(middle)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Your solution of changing middle =" " was a perfect fix.